# database for huge files like audio and video

Tags: database

My application creates a large number of files, each up to 100MB. Currently we store these files in the file system which works pretty well. But I am wondering if there is a better solution to store the files in a some kind of file database. The simple advantage with database is if it can split the file and store in small chunks instead of one 100mb file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file system is perfectly suited for storing files. If you need to associate them with a database, do it by filename. The filesystem already does numerous fancy things to assure it is efficient. It's probably best that you don't try to outsmart it.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases are no good at files this big.  You could go to something like [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/), but it may not be worth the trouble if what you have is doing the job.  I believe it does break large files down into chunks though.