# Can large sets of binary data can be store in Database?

Tags: mysql, linux, nosql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [database for huge files like audio and video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860979/database-for-huge-files-like-audio-and-video)

I'm seeking for the best (or at least good enough) way of storing large sets of binary data (images, videos, documents, etc.). The solution has to be scalable and can't get stuck after X amount of data.

I would like to have a one place for example MySQL database where all the data is kept. When one of web front ends needs it (on request) It can acquire it from the the DB and cache it permanently for later.

From this what I can see on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html MySQL table can't store more then 4TB per table. Is there something more appropriate like perhaps nosql databases or perhaps it's better to store everything in files on one server and propagate it to all web frontends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically don't want to store large files in a relational database -- it's not what they're designed for. I would also advise against using a NoSQL solution, since they're also typically not designed for this, although there are a few exceptions (see below).

Your last idea, storing the files on the filesystem (do note that this is what filesystems *are* designed for ;) is most likely the right approach. This can be somewhat difficult depending on what your scalability requirements are, but you will likely want to go with one of the following:

- **SAN.** SANs provide redundant, highly-available storage solutions within a network. Multiple servers can be attached to storage provided by a SAN and share files between each other. Note that this solution is typically enterprise-oriented and fairly expensive to implement reliably (you'll need physical hardware for it as well as RAID controllers and a lot of disks, at minimum).
- **CDN.** A content delivery network is a remote, globally distributed system for serving files to end users over the Internet. You typically put a file in a location on your server that is then replicated to the CDN for actual distribution. The way a CDN works is that if it doesn't have the file a user is requesting, it'll automatically try to fetch it from your server; once it has a copy of the file once, it caches the file for some period of time. It can be really helpful if you're normally constrained by bandwidth costs or processing overhead from serving up a huge number of files concurrently.
- **Cloud offering (Amazon S3, Rackspace Cloud Files).** These are similar to a CDN, but work well with your existing cloud infrastructure, if that's something you're using. You issue a request to the cloud API to store your file, and it subsequently becomes available over the Internet, just like with a CDN. The major difference is that you have to issue any storage requests (create, delete, or update) manually.

If the number of files you're serving is small, you can also go with an in-house solution. Store files on two or three servers (perhaps have a larger set of servers and use a hash calculation for sharding if space becomes an issue). Build a small API for your frontend servers to request files from your storage servers, falling back to alternate servers if one is unavailable.

One solution that I almost forgot (although I haven't ever used beyond research purposes) is Riak's [Luwak](https://github.com/basho/luwak) project. Luwak is an extension of Riak, which is an efficient distributed key/value store, that provides large file support by breaking the large files into consistently-sized segments and then storing those segments in a tree structure for quick access. It might be something to look into, because it gives you the redundancy, sharding, and API that I mentioned in the last paragraph for free.

Answer (score 3):

I work as a (volunteer) developer on a fairly large website - we have some 2GB of images in 14000 images [that's clearly nowhere near a "world record"], and a database of 150MB of database. Image files are stored as separate files instead of as database objects, partly because we resize images for different usages - thumbnails, medium and large images are created programattically from the stored image (which may be larger than the "large" size we use for the site).

Whilst it's possible to store "blobs" (Binary Large Objects) in SQL databases, I don't believe it's the best solution. Storing a reference in the database, so that you can make a path/filename combination for the actual stored file [and possibly hiding the actual image behind some sort of script - php, jsp, ruby or whatever you prefer] would be a better solution.